# Magento multiple 301 redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I'm working on a project and stuck on a strange problem. i'm trying to 301 redirect multiple urls (1800+) to new url.

```
Redirect 301 /old.cfm http://www.mysite.com/folder/new.html
```

Its working fine for single url, but when I'm trying to add multiple 301 urls its not working.

example,

```
Redirect 301 /old.cfm http://www.mysite.com/folder/new.html
Redirect 301 /old2.cfm http://www.mysite.com/folder1/folder2/new.html
```

what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Rather use Admin > CataLog > URL Rewrite Management

Create a custom rewrite and set 'Redirect' to 301